# Has the US Men's Soccer Team played a game outside of the USA or the host country?

Tags: football, trivia, fifa

It's become somewhat common for North or South American national soccer teams to play friendly games (or even sometimes non-friendlies) in the Untied States or Canada against another national team.

Has the US Men's National Soccer Team ever done something like this? i.e played a team in a non-tournament outside of either the USA or that team's country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [1987 Presidents Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_President%27s_Cup_Football_Tournament), USA were beaten 3-1 by Egypt in Seoul, South Korea.

In the same tournament, USA played CD Español in Masan, Thailand in Cheongju, Hungary in Daejeon and South Korea in Busan, all venues also in South Korea.

More recently, in 2010, [USA faced Australia](http://www.bigapplesoccer.com/us/mnt.php?article_id=22902) in Roodeport, South Africa as a warm-up game before the World Cup.

This is very similar to the preparation for the 2006 World cup, with the [USA having played Poland](http://www.ussoccer.com/news/mens-national-team/2006/02/u-s-mnt-touches-down-in-kaiserslautern-germany-in-advance-of-march-1-match-vs-poland.aspx) in Kaiserslautern, Germany.

Go back a little further to 1994 and you will find a match between [Romania and USA](http://www.11v11.com/matches/romania-v-usa-13-february-1994-244900/) that was played in the [Carlsberg Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_New_Year_Cup) Hong Kong.

The year before, in 1993, USA played in a [goalless draw against Hungary](http://articles.latimes.com/1993-03-11/sports/sp-1229_1_scoreless-tie) in Nagoya, Japan.

1975, in the Copa de Mexico, [USA played Costa Rica](http://www.11v11.com/matches/costa-rica-v-usa-19-august-1975-233423/) in Mexico City.

[FIFA](http://www.fifa.com/worldfootball/results/male.html#) lists all of these games as "friendlies".